# Active Event Type not appearing in CiviRules

Tags: civirules

Drupal 7.67, Civi 5.13.5

I'm currently adding some CiviRules to automatically tag users based on what event they sign up to / attend. However one of the event types isn't showing up in the CiviRule dropdown box on the "Conditions" screen. This event is marked as active. I haven't yet added any other Conditions for this CiviRule.

Any clue how to fix this?

Screenshots below -

My list of Event Types. I want to have a CiviRule that adds a tag when people attend a "Youth Event".
[image: The event type I want to integrate with CiviRules]

"Youth" doesn't appear in the drop-down:
[image: Youth Event not appearing 1]

Or when I search for it:
[image: Youth Event not appearing 2]

I haven't added any other Conditions for this CiviRule.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug I spotted last week and submitted a fix for.  Some of the new conditions in CiviRules 2.9 (including this one) are limited to just the first 10 options.  If you know how to apply a patch, [my fix is here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/merge_requests/21).  If not, this will get fixed in CiviRules 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Did it used to be "Youth" and you changed it at some point to "Youth Event"? Try changing it back to "Youth" just to see if that fixes it.